# Custom CameraActivity is shown on screen even after calling finish()

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-camera

I am having two activities: `HomeActivity` and `CameraActivity`. `HomeActivity` calls `CameraActivity` using intent with flag `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` and `startActivityForResult`. `CameraActivity` is having a fragment which opens a Custom Camera. I have given a button to capture image. If user clicks on button, capture callback of camera is called and in `onPictureTaken(byte[] data)` I am writing data array in image file and finishing activity by using `getActivity().finish()` and returning path of image file to `HomeActivity` and showing it on UI.

**Now the problem is:**

When I am calling `getActivity().finish()` from fragment in `CameraActivity`, it calls `onActivityResult` of `HomeActivity`. Path is shown on `TextView`. Logs are also printed properly from `HomeActivity`.  But on Screen Camera runs. Every time it requires back button to be pressed to end `CameraActivity`.
Suppose I am capturing image for once but because on screen camera is still running I tried to capture it twice, control returned on `HomeActivity` but `onActivityResult()` is not called for second capture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I was using fragments in Activity, when configuration changes occured, Activity is restarted and new instance of fragment is attached because of which it continued to showing unfinished fragment on screen.
I solved this problem by detaching fragment on configuration change.

Answer (score 4):

Debug the code. I think startActivityForResult is called multiple time.

Comment: No I have printed logs in startActivityForResult. Those are printed only once. That to for first call